# Using a WordPress featured image in a MailChimp RSS-to-Email campaign

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I'm using MailChimp to create a RSS-to-Email campaign based on a WordPress feed.

However, the FEEDITEM:IMAGE tag doesn't grab the featured image from my posts...

I've tried several solutions including dedicated plugins (like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-images-for-rss-feeds/) and customized feed-rss2.php (as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=mailchimp%20featured%20image).

Here is my HTML:

```
<table mc:repeatable="layout" mc:variant="1/1 Panel" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table class="table600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;">
                <tr>
                    <td height="50"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table align="center" class="table-inner" width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            *|FEEDBLOCK:http://louerunmanager.com/feed/|*
                            *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=1]|*
                            <!-- img -->
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px;" class="img1" alt="img" width="550" height="190">
                                    <img src="*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- end img -->

                            <tr>
                                <td height="25"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- title -->
                            <tr align="left" valign="top">
                                <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#3b3b3b; line-height:30px; font-weight: bold;" mc:edit="1/1 panel title">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- end title -->
                            <tr>
                                <td height="10"></td>
                            </tr>

                            <!-- content -->
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#7f8c8d; line-height:26px;" mc:edit="1/1 panel content">*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT_TEXT|*</td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- end content -->
                            *|END:FEEDITEMS|*
                            *|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the feed: http://louerunmanager.com/feed/.

As stated in MailChimp's documentation, FEEDITEM:IMAGE should display the content of media:content i.e. the featured image...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|* and the *|RSSITEM:IMAGE|* grab the `<media:content />` from the RSS feed, **not the url** from the image.

Instead of including the mailchimp tag as it is in the code in example:

```
<img src="*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*">
```

Try placing the tag by itself or inside the

```
<td>*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*</td>
```

or

```
<div>*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*</div>
```

It worked for me.
Check the example in the Mailchimp blog article: https://blog.mailchimp.com/rss-to-email-enhancement-for-publishers/